# saving multiple file upload server.mappath give DirectoryNotFoundException asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

i'm trying to select multiple image using file upload and save it to directory,and the goal is to display the image url,i don't use any plugin to multiple upload

so this is the designer :

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" onchange="updateList()"/> <br/>
<asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Upload File" onclick="Button4_Click"/>
```

i'ts working well if i do the single file upload.now im trying to save more images at the same time
this is my code behind :

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
  int i = 0;
  foreach (var img in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
  {
    string filePath = img.FileName;
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
    string contenttype = string.Empty;
    switch (ext)
    {
      case ".jpg":
       contenttype = "image/jpg";break;
      case ".png":
       contenttype = "image/png";break;
      case ".gif":
       contenttype = "image/gif";break;
    }
    if (contenttype != String.Empty)
    {
      try
      {
        string fullpath= Server.MapPath("~/images/TmpE/" + filename + "");
        img.SaveAs(fullpath);
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "successupload" + i, @"uploadSuccess('" + fullpath + "');", true);
        i++;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Label2.Text = "exception : " + ex.ToString();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this code always catch exception:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
>   path 'C:\ClientSites\sample.com\httpdocs\images\TmpE\sample.png'

Comment: Have you verified the directory `C:\ClientSites\sample.com\httpdocs\images\TmpE\.` exists?

Comment: @KobyDouek yes i alr verify, and the directory is't exist, i think it's caused by "C:\ClientSites"

Comment: If the directory does not exist, why are you surprised you are getting an error?! You need to specify a path that **exists on the running server**!

Comment: @KobyDouek i'm not surprised for the error, but why Server.MapPath() give me wrong path/directory, should i write the directory manually ?

Comment: See my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you wrote in the comments:

> *"Yes, I verified, and the directory doesn't exist"*

Then there's no surprise you're getting this error message. If you are asking your server to save a file in a directory that doesn't exist, it will throw you a `DirectoryNotFoundException`.

Either change your line:

```
Server.MapPath("~/images/TmpE/" + filename + "");
```

To a directory that **does exist** (and has sufficiant writing privillages)

Or, create the directory `C:\ClientSites\sample.com\httpdocs\images\TmpE\` (again, with sufficiant writing privillages), manually, or via code (`File.Directory.CreateDirectory`).

For instance:

```
string savePath = Server.MapPath("~/images/TmpE/");
if (!Directory.Exsits(savePath))
     Directory.CreateDirectory(savePath);

// Now you've made sure the directory exists, save the file.
```

Comment: thanks for your solution.now i understand what happen. i create a new folder/path manually to save the img in vs framework, its work in localserver run.and error come after publishing to the study server coz the new folder/path not published to the server so server.mappath() give directorynotfoundexception

Comment: @waycold Happy to help. Have a great day and happy coding.